# Delete document from mongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

This might be a really stupid question, but I'm new to MongoDB, so bear with me. I've created a stand alone ruby class:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

require 'bson'
require 'mongo_mapper'

MongoMapper.database = "testing"

class Twit
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :id,          Integer, :unique => true
  key :screen_name, String,  :unique => true

...
```

Then I do the following with irb

```
>> twit = Twit.all.first
 => #<Twit _id: BSON::ObjectId('4df2d4a0c251b2754c000001'), id: 21070755, screen_name: "bguestSB"> 
>> twit.destroy
 => true 
>> Twit.all
 => [#<Twit _id: BSON::ObjectId('4df2d4a0c251b2754c000001'), id: 21070755, screen_name: "bguestSB">]
```

So how do I destroy documents in MongoDB? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: What happens if you `Twit.find('4df2d4a0c251b2754c000001').destroy` and then `Twit.all`?

Comment: @mu, the entry seems to remain. The only way I've been able to get rid of documents saved into the DB is to drop the whole data base. Is there something with the way that my system is set up that could be preventing the documents from being deleted?

Comment: That should work, works for me at least. Have you tried using the MongoDB command line shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help on this issue. For anyone else who has this problem, I believe it is because I forgot to add the the location of the mongodb binary files to the `$PATH` variable

In my case installed the binary files in `/usr/local/mongodb/bin` as such I needed to add `export PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 4):

Imagine, that you want to delete all the document with empty "name"-field. So here is the code for it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost").db("db_name")
coll = db.collection("coll_name")

coll.find({:name => ""}).each do |empty_doc|
  coll.remove(empty_doc)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about ruby, but with the command line shell it is:

```
db.Twit.remove({_id: '4df2d4a0c251b2754c000001'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to delete document by ID:

```
collection.remove({"_id" => BSON::ObjectId("4df2d4a0c251b2754c000001")})
```