# Removing fields automatically

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am new to Mongodb. So please guide me with this issue. I have a collection of docs and want to delete unnecessary fields from collection. Is there any automated method? I know that I can use **$unset** but it seems if I want to delete many fields then I have to repeat this operation for each field am I right? I have found that I can do it using ruby according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314139/delete-document-from-mongodb) but what about removing not all fields but some of them?

Comment: If the field is just unnecessary, but does not cause problems with the application (or the law), an option would be to just leave it in, maybe removing it when the document is next updated. Bulk-updating is a lot of work, and unless the documents shrink a lot, it does not even save space.

Comment: This is a good idea, but may cause trouble if your schema changes very often and your app needs always the latest as you don't want to have several dozen comparision checks for each retrieval of a document.

Answer (score 1):

With `$unset` you would be able to delete (arbitrary) many fields at once. Together with a multi update you'll get something like an automated method. So to delete only some fields lets consider this example doc: `{_id:OID, a: { b: 2, c: 3}, d : [1,2]}` you can use this: `$unset : {"a.b" : 1, d : 1}` to delete the nested element b in a, as well as the array d.

If you want to delete only some items of an array I believe you have to work with the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), but I didn't work with it.

Comment: okThanks! Do you know how I can do this with ruby? I just cant understand this http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#remove-instance_method

Comment: The remove command is something you don't want to use as this removes documents matching your search criteria rather than unsetting given fields. You should use update instead. Example usage could be something like, without beeing valid Ruby-Syntax I guess (I'm not familiar with that): `collection.update({"$exists" : { "fieldToRemove": true}},{"$unset" : {"fieldToRemove" : 1}}, {multi=true})`.